# Efficiently buffer data before sending it through websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

My application sends small packets too quick through websocket. Sending small packets quickly is inefficient in terms of bandwidth. Sending more data in bulk makes it smaller (compression).

How can I efficiently buffer data (binary, Uint8ClampedArray) at client side and send only after x time (ms)?

I tried merging arrays into one and send only after x time but merging them is turning out to be inefficient (CPU).

http://jsperf.com/merge-in-array-vs-typed-array